# How to override two methods of 2 parents that inherits same classes with virtual methods in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtual

Consider the next Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
    public:
    virtual void f() {
        std::cout << "Base::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base 
{
    public:
    virtual void f() override
    {
        Base::f();
        std::cout << "Derived1::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base 
{
    public:
    virtual void f() override
    {
        Base::f();
        std::cout << "Derived2::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class DerivedUnion : public Derived1, public Derived2
{
    public:
    void Derived1::f() override { // Errors

    }

    void Derived2::f() override { // Errors

    }

};
```

is there some how that allow me to override the
`Derived2::f()`
in the
`DerivedUnion{}`
class?

I have tried to target specific one with namespace like style, but it didnt worked:

```
class DerivedUnion : public Derived1, public Derived2 
   // Notice DerivedUnion is not a Union, name is for
   // Demostration Purposes, not intended to create
   // A union Behavior
{
    public:
    virtual void Derived1::f() override; // Compile error
    virtual void Derived2::f() override; // Compile error
    virtual void f() override; // Not a compile error, but both Derived1 and Derived2 call same
};

void UseBase(Base* b){
       b->f(); // expected Ambiguos call compile time
       b->DerivedUnion::f() // Expected overriden DerivedUnion::f() to be called
       b->Derived1::f(); // Expected overriden Derived1::f() to be called
       b->Derived2::f(); // Expected overriden Derived2::f() to be called
}
```

An Example of it could be this one, code is self explanatory:

```
#include <iostream>

/* Interface Drawable */
class IDrawable {
    public:
    
    virtual void Draw() {};
};

/* Asume this is a button from one kind of bar */
class ButtonA : public IDrawable{
    public:
    virtual void Draw() override {
        std::cout << "ButtonA::Draw()" << std::endl;
    }
};

/* Asume this is a button from another kind of bar */
class ButtonB : public IDrawable{
    public:
    virtual void Draw() override {
        std::cout << "ButtonB::Draw()" << std::endl;
    }
};

/**
Where Component X is a representation that will represent 2 buttons types
*/
class ComponentX : public ButtonA, public ButtonB {
    public:
    void ButtonA::Draw() override { // cannot define member function ‘ButtonA::Draw’ within ‘ComponentX’
        ButtonA::Draw();
        std::cout << "Custom ComponentX::Draw()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void ButtonB::Draw() override { // error: cannot define member function ‘ButtonB::Draw’ within ‘ComponentX’
        ButtonB::Draw();
        std::cout << "Custom ComponentX::Draw()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ComponentY : public ButtonA, public ButtonB {
    public:
    void ButtonA::Draw() override { // cannot define member function ‘ButtonA::Draw’ within ‘ComponentY’
        ButtonA::Draw();
        std::cout << "Custom ComponentY::Draw()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void ButtonB::Draw() override { // error: cannot define member function ‘ButtonB::Draw’ within ‘ComponentY’
        ButtonB::Draw();
        std::cout << "Custom ComponentY::Draw()" << std::endl;
    }
};

using namespace std;

void DummyAddButtonA(ButtonA* pBtnA)
{
    //Add it somewhere ...
}

void DummyAddButtonB(ButtonB* pBtnB)
{
    //Add it somewhere ...
}

int main()
{
    ComponentX compx;
    ComponentY compy;
    
    DummyAddButtonA(&compx);
    DummyAddButtonB(&compx);

    DummyAddButtonA(&compy);
    DummyAddButtonB(&compy);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking here. Your `DerivedUnion` implementation overrides *both* `Derived1::f` and `Derived2::f`. What do you want to achieve instead?

Comment: @KonradRudolph He want’s to have 3 different override functions. Not possible. Apart from intermediate classes.

Comment: whats the actual aim? why do you think you need this?

Comment: This is example of [`Deadly diamond of death`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). Not sure why you think you need to override separately each branch of inheritance. You are overriding just `Base::f`.

Comment: Nope, this cannot be done. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @MarekR It isn't really a Diamond of Death since `DerivedUnion` *is* overriding `f`. The DoD only occurs if a common virtual method method is *not* overridden by the leaf class. Though of course knowledge of the DoD is still very relevant for OP.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph
i left it there as view of compilation, more down i specified the behaviour i didnt want

Comment: "C++ does not work this way", yes i realized that and did redesign what i was doing, but i kept with the curiosity why. so i decided to ask

Comment: Unclear what you want to achieve. an example of usage with expected output might help.

Comment: union has special meaning in C++, so `DerivedUnion` name might be misleading, it has both `DerivedN` as base (and so 2 `Base`), not only one of them.

Comment: @Jarod42 added an example where ilustrate what i want to achieve, also notice i can do separated class and specialize it there, but i dont want, i wanned to do it lazy way as show there

Comment: @Jarod42 DerivedUnion Was just a demo name, i wasnt trying to do some kind of cpp union behavior

Comment: C++ union behavior is done in C++17 with `std::variant`. It is a safe implementation of a union.

Comment: `DerivedUnion` has only one `f`. What do you want to happen when you do say `Base* b = new DeribedUnion; b->f();`?

Comment: In your examples, you never call `f`/`Draw` (with expected output)...

Comment: @n. m what i wanted to happend?, some kind of ambiguos call compile error, so then i can cast any of the custom buttons i implemented and call it

Comment: @n.m. there is a quick demo of calling, and expected behaviors in function UseBase()

Comment: How can it possibly be a compile error? Where? `b->f();` doesn't know there are derived classes. It can be in a translation unit that have never seen any derived class. It can be written and compiled before any derived class was written.

Comment: If you use `::`, the virtual call mechanism is not used. If you want to use the virtual call mechanism, do not use `::`. If you want to use the virtual call mechanism *and* have two different virtual functions, give them two different names.

Comment: @n. m. Exactly the answer i was finding, Thanks